# where is ALT + . setting to call previous parameter stored

Tags: linux, bash, dotfiles

I have installed some dotfiles which have over ridden ALT + "." to call the last parameter to previous command. Where is this setting stored by default as I m guessing these dotfiles must have over ridden that .

Comment: .bash_completion ? you can try rename those files still it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be set by a `bind` command in any of your startup files such as `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, etc. Or it can be set in `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc`.

The default, if nothing is set explicitly, is set internally in Bash.